# alignment of the axis and data labeles in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

I took an interesting sample of ggplot here and remade it for my data 
My data is excel file

`

```
col <- c("Low weight", "very low weight", "Extra Very Low weight", "Cesarean section", "premature")
> ORpos <- c(6.8, 4.5,0.4, 4.5, 3.9)
> CI1 <- c(0.6, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0.4)
> CI2 <- c(74, 56, 32, 20, 2.4)
> ORneg <- c(4.8, 15, 6, 6, 4)
> CI3 <- c(0.6, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0.4)
> CI4 <- c(56, 43, 21, 10, 5)
> md4 <- data.frame(col,ORpos, CI1, CI2, ORneg, CI3, CI4)
 
plot3 <- ggplot(md4, aes(x = col)) +
  geom_col( 
    aes(y = Orp, fill = 'Orp')) +geom_text(aes(y=Orp, label = paste(Orp, " [", CI1," ; ", CI2, "]", sep = ""), hjust = -1))+
  geom_col( 
    aes(y = -Orn, fill = 'Orn')) + geom_text(aes(y=-Orn, label = paste(Orn, " [", CI3," ; ", CI4, "]", sep = ""), hjust = 1))+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-30, 30))

plot3
```

But this is where my understanding of R ended completely. 
[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xFa5.png)

1. Why is order my variables in the plot not order as in the table ???

2 What to do to data labels would be on the right and left edges of the plot or at least exactly under each other

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be easier to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data shared via `dput()`.

Comment: Please share your sample data as copy/pasteble text, preferably in valid R syntax as produced by eg., `dput(md4[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows. We can't test solutions on a screenshot of a table of data.

Comment: As for the ordering, `ggplot` will implicitly coerce categorical variables to `factor` class, and the default ordering for `factor` levels is alphabetical. You can set your own order--if you want the order as the first appear in the data than `md4$col = factor(md4$col, levels = unique(md4$col))` will do it. For other orders [you can find lots of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bggplot2%5D+%5Br-faq%5D+order).

Comment: Orp is not in the dataframe at all

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue of reordering you need to transform your character column to factors (as Gregor pointed out) via `md4$col = factor(md4$col, levels = unique(md4$col))` or just `md4$col = factor(md4$col, levels = md4$col)` as apparently you don't have repeating values in your column.

For the second issue as far as I know `hjust` should be between 0 to 1 for left and right justified text relative to your datapoint respectively, so you may want to set it 0 for your ORpos and 1 for ORneg data and then extend your scales to fit in all text, hope this helps:

```
md4$col = factor(md4$col, levels = rev(md4$col))

ggplot(md4, aes(x = col)) +
  geom_col( aes(y = ORpos, fill = 'Positive culter')) +
  geom_text(aes(y=7, label = paste(ORpos, " [", CI1,"; ", CI2, "]", sep = " "), hjust = 0))+
  geom_col( aes(y = -ORneg, fill = 'Negative culter')) +
  geom_text(aes(y=-7, label = paste(ORneg, " [", CI3,"; ", CI4, "]", sep = " "), hjust = 1))+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10), breaks = c(-10:10))
```

Comment: md4$col = factor(md4$col, levels = md4$col (!!!) This is working! For unknown fo me  reason  the order is the reverse of the table, but it works!

Comment: If you want to reverse the order just use `levels=rev(md4$col)`

Comment: I have added data frame.    I am using  different options hajust. But the labels "dance" relative to the bars. Not readable.

Comment: plot3 <- ggplot(md4, aes(x = col)) +
    geom_col( 
    aes(y = Orp, fill = 'Positive culter')) +geom_text(aes(y=3, label = paste(Orp, " [", CI1,"; ", CI2, "]", sep = " ", "p=", p1), hjust = 0))+
  geom_col( 
    aes(y = -Orn, fill = 'Negative culter')) + geom_text(aes(y=-3, label = paste(Orn, " [", CI3,"; ", CI4, "]", sep = " ", "p=", p2), hjust = 1))+
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10), breaks = c(-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7) )

plot3 [Did I break anything important?  replaced y with a number, not the value of a variable]

Comment: Saw your table, glad that I could be of a help. But your code in the comment is still not reproducible what are `p1` and `p2`? I have polished it for you and updated my answer, take a look. good luck!